# spring webflow submit form on link

Tags: spring-webflow

I have following problem.

I want to save the details entered by the user in the database using  SpringWebflow.     The requirement is that the user has to click `Save as Draft` link instead of a submit button.

I want to capture the details entered/selected by the user and send it as an object( i don't want to set request parameters because there are more than 20 fields throughout the flow).

Below is my code snippet. P.S, there are no errors. I can see the logs in the service being written.

```
step1.jsp

<form:form commandName="userEnteredCriteria" action="${flowExecutionUrl}" method="post">

<div class="submit-buttons submit-style">
            <input type="submit" name="_eventId_next" value="next"     class="submit-button product-submit"/>
</div>


<p class="return product-submit1"><a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=saveDraftStep1">Save as Draft</a></p>

</form:form>

weblflow.xml

<view-state id="Step1">
 <transition on="saveDraftStep1">
 <evaluate expression="myAction.bindAndValidate" /> 
 <evaluate expression="myFlowService.saveDraft(userEnteredCriteria        externalContext.nativeRequest)" />
 </transition>
</view-state>
```

Can someone please help me with how to submit the form on link click? I know i have to right some javascript( please correct me if i am wrong) but i don't know how to do it in javascirpt. we are using JQUERY for javascript. any sample code will hlp

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" id="saveDraftStep1" name="_eventId_saveDraftStep1" value="saveDraftStep1" style="display:none;"/>
<a href onclick="document.getElementById('saveDraftStep1').click();">Click here to save draft</a>
```